# Where to store cert file for Kibana in Docker

Tags: docker, kibana, kibana-7

I have to run the Kibana server in a Docker container and connect it to the ElasticSearch cluster that has enabled basic security through private VNET.

I'm using Kibana v. 7.17.3
I'm copying cert and yml file during the build stage, like:
COPY kibana.yml /usr/share/kibana/
COPY *.p12 /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/

However, the Kibana server is not ready yet. Perhaps the paths are wrong because on the local machine the same config and cert work fine with the cluster.

Could you please advise the proper paths for cert?

Comment: This seems like you're deploying an ELK stack, more than doing actual software development.  Another site like [devops.se] or [sf] might be a more appropriate place to ask this sort of question.

Comment: do you have an error message?

Comment: Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Comment: I've configured Kibana on the VM (not a container) with default paths for config and cert and everything works as expected. The problem is only in a container and only with a cert.
Kibana works in the container but doesn't connect to cluster.